# How to proceed with my piano playing?

Tags: piano

I've learned piano in high school for a semester. There, I acquired a bit experience on it, or at least enough to make me play simple songs. Its been almost 2 years since that course I took, but I don't know where to continue. It just seems there are too many things I could practice, but I have no idea if I have the knowledge required to study them. What should I do? How do I find what "level" I am? I also have to note that I'm by myself, I don't have enough money to pay a course or hire a teacher.

I don't really have a defined objective. I just want to be capable of having a extensive collection of songs which I can play myself, complicated and simple ones. Other than that, I can't define a goal for myself.

Comment: Your question is to open to give some reasonable advice apart look for a piano teacher. It would help a lot if you could tell more precisely  in what direction you want to progress.
in my concern I could say: any style. Baroque, classic, modern, pop, jazz everything. now you? If it were songs, you can make a liste and I  could tell you what could be some "stage and sequence" you can go to a music shop  and ask for a liste of easy piano pieces. If you can decide for any tag you will get a lot of help here. so  I can't say more than watch youtube tutorials and find some songs that you can play.

Answer (score 2):

When you mention "songs" I think you mean a pop style or maybe jazz.

The Trinity series Tanmay suggested is "classical" in style not pop/jazz.

You can find beginner and intermediate resources in various styles, but I think there is a lot of established pegagoical (teaching) material in classical style that is either explicitly graded or title by the composer with various keywords like "progressive, easy, or intermediate, etc."

- [Practical Exercises for Beginners, Op.599 (Czerny, Carl)](https://imslp.org/wiki/Practical_Exercises_for_Beginners,_Op.599_(Czerny,_Carl))
- [25 Easy and Progressive Studies (Burgmuller)](https://imslp.org/wiki/25_%C3%89tudes_faciles_et_progressives%2C_Op.100_(Burgm%C3%BCller%2C_Friedrich))
- [Introduction to the Art of Playing the Piano Forte (Clementi)](https://imslp.org/wiki/Introduction_to_the_Art_of_Playing_the_Pianoforte%2C_Op.42_(Clementi%2C_Muzio))

Also, there are several famous notebooks from the great composers which they created to teach family members.

- [Nannerl Notebook (Mozart, Leopold)](https://imslp.org/wiki/Nannerl%27s_Music_Book_(Mozart%2C_Leopold))
- [Anna Magdalena Notebook (Bach, JS)](https://imslp.org/wiki/Notebooks_for_Anna_Magdalena_Bach_(Bach%2C_Johann_Sebastian))

You can find lots more like those from the classical literature.

If you want pop/jazz styles, there are also introductory method books. These type resources don't seem to be graded typically, but their titles usually indicate beginner material. Some are produced in series covering various styles. Here are some examples.

- Rock Keyboard - The Complete Guide with Online Audio!: Hal Leonard Keyboard S... [https://www.amazon.com/dp/0634039814](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0634039814)
- Modern Pop Keyboard - The Complete Guide with Audio: Hal Leonard Keyboard Sty... [https://www.amazon.com/dp/1495025071](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1495025071)
- Improvising Blues Piano by Tim Richards [https://www.amazon.com/dp/0946535973](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0946535973)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the simplest way to go about this is to follow the Trinity College of London's Books. They have an interesting progression across the levels and you end up learning a lot as you play.
They have a theory and a practical book for every level. The theory books contain all the information needed to play the music in the practical book of the same grade.

Besides the books from Trinity College, you always have youtube. Look for things that you don't understand and then end up learning more than you expected.

Thats my two cents. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Well you say you don't have a well defined objective, but you do. Learning a collection of easy to hard songs is a most sensible objective. Maybe you just need to make this objective concrete by jotting down the actual list of  tunes you plan to learn.

I'd simply select 3 or 4 songs that really excite me, and keep at them till I can play them. If this will be you main goal, then any technical exercises will be just a consequence of stumbling blocks you hit while learning these songs. The best kind of practice is always focused, goal oriented and pushing forward (in a sense - you practice the stuff that you can't play well, as oppose to practicing what you already know).

So for example if you stumble upon a fast run in a Chopin piece, then practice the scale, right fingerings ect. This way you will build up the technical abilities while getting a great satisfaction of being able to play more and more songs.